# Number of processor ticks for thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, processor

I need to know how many ticks of processor used by thread knowing its thread id. Because processor in PC is a synchronous device, if my thread is working, it takes processor time. I need to see what threads in my process are working. How can i do this? I'm using C++ in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Have you tried "Process Explorer" - it has a thread view for a given process, which tells you how much CPU time and what is blocking a given thread.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yes i tried "Process Explorer". But i need to add functional of CPU time for thread to my application.

Comment: You mean you need to, in your code, find out how much CPU time a particular thread has used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to get thread statistics in your code, you can use [`GetThreadTimes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which gives you a value for time used in kernel mode and time used in user mode for the thread given to the function. It gives you the total time, so if you want to measure how much CPU usage a thread has, you need to track the previous value (I started writing some code to show that, but since `FILETIME` is not that easy to deal with, I gave up - I also can't testcompile it, since I don't have Windows machine...)